# É possível reiniciar o servidor do NodeJS quando ocorrer uma modificação automaticamente?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Toda vez que eu tento fazer alguma modificação no meu arquivo `app.js` tenho que fechar e iniciar o servidor para que as modificações tenham efeito, teria alguma forma de reiniciar automaticamente depois de uma mudança? como no php.

**Exemplo:**

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write("<h1>Hello World!</h1>"); // <-- se mudar o texto no F5 não atualiza.
    response.end();
});

var servidorLigou = function () {
    console.log('Servidor Hello World rodando!');
};

server.listen(3000,servidorLigou);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um [supervisor](https://blog.risingstack.com/operating-node-in-production/) para essa função. Uma alternativa para esse papel é o [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon).

Para instalar é bem simples, como mostra o site:

```
$ npm install nodemon -g
$ nodemon app.js
```

[Esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1972242/4843158) possui diversas opções de **supervisors** e como utilizar, caso tenha interesse.

Comment: Opa, era isto mesmo. então eu devo usar o `forever` em produção e o nodemon em desenvolvimento? não sei por que isso não vem por padrão o.O

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues não vem por padrão porque há mais maneiras de fazer e são soluções independentes e específicas do ambiente (sistema operativo do servidor) em que o Node correr.